# Credentials to use for Azure DevOps Power Query

Tags: azure, azure-devops, powerquery

I'm trying this question for a second time since I wasn't clear enough last time....

I've managed to set up an Excel workbook which is connected to query DevOps for Work Item data, so that I can look and see what work people are estimating they'll complete and also what they are actually completing.

I've connected with my organizational account using:

[https://analytics.dev.azure.com/[Org]/_odata/V1.0](https://analytics.dev.azure.com/%5BOrg%5D/_odata/V1.0)

This was probably short-sighted of me because others have learned of this workbook and want sight of it, but when I send it to them though it won't automatically refresh - it keeps asking for credentials instead, and for one person who did put in their credentials it didn't show the full information - there were people that couldn't be selected from the slicer (presumably because these people are part of projects that he is not a member of).

How can I resolve this so I can share the workbook with everyone and it will show them the live data just as it would for me even if they're a standard user (essentially they need to see all work item estimates and completed times for all projects in the organization)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test, click the share button as shown in the figure below to invite people. The invited people do not need to enter credentials.

[image]

[image]

Or you can generate a public PAT token and provide it to people as a basic credential

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Hugh - I don't think this would give others the same values as I see due to the different project permissions though would it?

Comment: Click the share button as shown in the answer to invite people. The invited people do not need to enter credentials

Comment: Just going off the first screenshots, if sharing, would person B be able to refresh the data?

Comment: Click this [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNMWg.png) and people should be able to refresh the data

Comment: Perfect thank you... I had the pieces, I couldn't fit them together. Much appreciated.